# How to export a html file as PDF file on clientside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I need to export pdf file from html file on click of a button. Tried jspdf to export pdf from html but    jspdf doesn't support CSS and IE doesn't support this method. Is  there any other method to export pdf   from html on client side with all css property and images on html page.

Comment: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF and here is demo as well http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/convert-html-to-pdf-with-dompdf/

Comment: @MohitArora Thank you so much but the problem is IE does not support jsPDF.

Comment: @Tapaswini if you check downloadify in example folder that will work in all browser

Comment: @MohitArora I have checked downloadify in example folder but it's not working in any browser. I have flash player installed in my desktop but still its not working.  Can you please help me on this ?